# Run Wiremock on HTTPS with Webdriver IO

Tags: android, https, webdriver-io, wiremock

I'm using WebdriverIO to run my tests on an Android phone. I would like to use Wiremock to mock the request coming from the phone. The Android application's configuration requires HTTPS connections.

I use the following configuration to run Wiremock on HTTP:

```
  services: [
    [
      'wiremock',
      {
        rootDir: './testing/sit/configs/wiremock',
        port: 8181,
        args: ['--enable-stub-cors', '--print-all-network-traffic']
      }
    ]
  ],
```

How can I modify it to HTTPS?
For the standalone Wiremock it's the following, but I could not find any examples for WebrdiverIO configuration:

```
java -jar wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.35.0.jar --https-port 8181 --print-all-network-traffic --verbose --enable-stub-cors --https-keystore ./identity.jks
```

I tried the following configuration, but it did not work:

```
  services: [
    [
      'wiremock',
      {
        rootDir: './testing/sit/configs/wiremock',
        args: ['--enable-stub-cors', '--print-all-network-traffic', '--https-port 8181']
      }
    ]
  ],
```